# Clone is not working for me?

Tags: php, clone

I have an object `$objDummy` of some class `ClassDummy` and another is as

`$objClone = clone $objDummy;`

Then I make any change in `$objClone`, `$objDummy` is also changed.
I do not want to do that.
How can I get this to work?

EDIT:
In response to Chris.
Here is an example

```
<?php
class myAnotherObject{
    public $myAnotherVar =10;
}

class myObject {
    public $myVar = false;
    function __construct() {
        $this->myVar = new myAnotherObject();
    }
}


$nl = "\n";
//*
$nl = '<br />';
//*/


$obj1 = new myObject();
echo 'obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar;

$obj2 = clone $obj1;

echo $nl.'obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar.', obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar;

$obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar = 20;
echo $nl.'obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar.', obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar;
```

The output is

```
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10, obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 20, obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: 20
```

Comment: Just a little note: The () braces are not needed for clone as it is not a function but works more like the "new" operator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you implementing the `__clone()` method? The examples in the [PHP documentation on cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) will explain this better than I possibly can. Specifically you're interested in this part,

> When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will
>   perform a shallow copy of all of the
>   object's properties. Any properties
>   that are references to other
>   variables, will remain references.
>
> Once the cloning is complete, if a
>   __clone() method is defined, then the newly created object's __clone()
>   method will be called, to allow any
>   necessary properties that need to be
>   changed.

**UPDATE**
 
Based on your update to the question, you're indeed missing the implementation of `__clone()`. Since the `$myVar` member of `myObject` is itself an object, you need to clone that as well. Here's what your `myObject` class should look like,

```
class myObject {
    public $myVar = false;
    function __construct() {
        $this->myVar = new myAnotherObject();
    }

    function __clone() {
        $this->myVar = clone $this->myVar;
    }
}
```

The output then becomes the following,

```
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10, obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10, obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: 20
```

Comment: please check again the question. And let me know haw can I get the solution.

Comment: OMG, It is so simple solution. I must have read the doc carefully. Anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate your results.  Using the code below, I get the expected output (copied below the code).  The ___clone() method is not required for this, as illustrated.  Can you post a slimmed-down version of your code?

**CODE**

```
class myObject {
    public $myVar = false;
    function __construct($newVar=5) {
        $this->myVar = $newVar;
    }
}

$nl = "\n";
//*
$nl = '<br />';
//*/


$obj1 = new myObject(10);
echo 'obj1->myVar: '.$obj1->myVar;

$obj2 = clone $obj1;
echo $nl.'obj1->myVar: '.$obj1->myVar.', obj2->myVar: '.$obj2->myVar;

$obj1->myVar = 20;
echo $nl.'obj1->myVar: '.$obj1->myVar.', obj2->myVar: '.$obj2->myVar;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
obj1->myVar: 10
obj1->myVar: 10, obj2->myVar: 10
obj1->myVar: 20, obj2->myVar: 10
```

Edited after discussion:

Your issue is caused by a reference to an object.  Since all objects are handled by reference, when you clone an object you also need to clone any internally held objects, otherwise you end up with a reference to a single object.

**CODE**

```
class myAnotherObject{
    public $myAnotherVar =10;
}

class myObject {
    public $myVar = false;
    function __construct() {
        $this->myVar = new myAnotherObject();
    }
    function __clone() {
        $this->myVar = clone $this->myVar;  
    }
}


$nl = "\n";
//*
$nl = '<br />';
//*/


$obj1 = new myObject();
echo 'obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar;

$obj2 = clone $obj1;

echo $nl.'obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar.', obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar;

$obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar = 20;
echo $nl.'obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar.', obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: '.$obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10, obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10
obj1->myVar->myAnotherVar: 10, obj2->myVar->myAnotherVar: 20
```

Comment: The @Rich Adams was correct.  I will edit my answer to demonstrate.  The __clone() method will take good care of you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but not for objects with methods ->

```
function cloneObj(&obj) {
 return json_decode(json_encode($obj));
}

$a = new stdClass();
$b = cloneObj($a);
```