# __clone() vs unserialize(serialize())?

Tags: php, serialization, clone

With the reference of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959949/clone-is-not-working-for-me) question, I got an another solution is
use

```
$obj2 = unserialize(serialize($obj1));
```

instead of

```
$obj2 = clone $obj1;
```

Which one is better to use?

Comment: clone, but i don't know if i can 'prove' it.

Comment: @Dagon : I agree. But any explanation will be good.

Comment: what philwinkle said :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr version:** Use `clone` for simple objects and trees, `unserialize(serialize())` for complicated graphs of objects.

**Longer explanation:** Unless `$obj1` implements `__clone()`, the expression `clone $obj1` will return a shallow copy of `$obj1`, but sharing the contents of objects pointed to by `$obj1`.  Even if `__clone()` is implemented to perform a deep copy by recursive `clone` of members, it will only work safely if the object graph is a tree.  If the object graph contains cycles, it will recurse indefinitely and... well... this is Stack Overflow for a reason. :-)  If it is a directed acyclic graph but not a tree, any object referenced multiple times will have those multiple references replaced by copies, which may not be what you want.

`unserialize(serialize($obj1))`, on the other hand, will deal with cycles in the object graph, but is more expensive in terms of both CPU time and memory.

Comment: +1 for "shallow clone", and the potential problems with deep cloning

Answer (score 3):

Sure, that creates a clone, but with incredible overhead and without the ability to actually define any settings or behaviors using the __clone magic method.

I would use the clone keyword and if you're in need of further research see the comments section at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php for proofs that cloning doesn't require that a change to one object persists to its clone.