# Appending to array replaces all elements in the array

Tags: php, arrays, replace, append

I'm building an array of rows from a DB using the code below.

```
$site = new stdClass();    
$dbh = _vic_commander_db();
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, title, url FROM site ORDER BY siteid');
    $sth->bindColumn(1, $site->name);
    $sth->bindColumn(2, $site->title);
    $sth->bindColumn(4, $site->url);

    $sth->execute();
    $ret = array();
    while ($sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND))
    {
        $ret[] = $site;
    }
```

The array ($ret[]) does get added to each iteration of the loop; however in addition to APPENDING each of the rows of the table, all elements get REPLACED by the last result appended. So I have an array with the same number of elements as rows in the table but the elements are all the same.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Example out:

```
    array(3) (
      [0] => stdClass object {
        name => (string) Same Site Name
        title => (string) Same Site Title
        url => (string) samepurl.com
      }
      [1] => stdClass object {
        name => (string) Same Site Name
        title => (string) Same Site Title
        url => (string) samepurl.com
      }
      [2] => stdClass object {
        name => (string) Same Site Name
        title => (string) Same Site Title
        url => (string) samepurl.com
        }
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer has a decent explanation, but why not just fetch into an array of objects?

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, title, url FROM site ORDER BY siteid');
$ret = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Answer (score 2):

All the array indexes point to the same object `$site`.

You have to copy by value instead of by reference:

```
$ret[] = clone $site;
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Also I wonder why you really need to store an object here.

Comment: As I see, fetching into an array was okay for you, so just for the record, why clone could have failed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959949/clone-is-not-working-for-me

Answer (score 0):

try this way, according to documentation ( `execute()` before `bindColumn()` ):

```
$site = new stdClass();    
$dbh = _vic_commander_db();
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, title, url FROM site ORDER BY siteid');
    $sth->execute();

    $sth->bindColumn(1, $site->name);
    $sth->bindColumn(2, $site->title);
    $sth->bindColumn(4, $site->url); //could you explain why 4?? not 3 ???

    $ret = array();
    while ($sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND))
    {
        $ret[] = $site;
    }
```