# ZF2 hydrators and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework2, clone

I have a problem with a **ArraySerializable** hydrator and arrays. I have this code:

```
$users = array();
$produtos = array();
$ros = $this->roService->findAllEntities();
foreach ($ros as $ro) {
    $users[] = $this->usuarioService->findEntity($ro->attributes['idUsuario']->attribute);
    $produtos[] = $this->produtoService->findEntity($ro->attributes['idProduto']->attribute);
    var_dump($produtos[0]->attributes);
}
```

Here is the output of **var_dump($produtos[0]->attributes)** on two iterations:

```
array (size=3)
'id' => 
  object(Application\Model\Attribute\Id)[307]
    protected 'name' => string 'id' (length=2)
    protected 'attribute' => string '2' (length=1)
    protected 'validators' => 
      array (size=0)
        empty
'dataHoraCadastro' => 
  object(Application\Model\Attribute\DataHoraCadastro)[308]
    protected 'name' => string 'dataHoraCadastro' (length=16)
    protected 'attribute' => string '2015-03-07 14:03:37' (length=19)
    protected 'validators' => 
      array (size=0)
        empty
'nome' => 
  object(Application\Model\Attribute\Nome)[309]
    protected 'name' => string 'nome' (length=4)
    protected 'validators' => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => 
          object(Application\Validator\StringLengthValidator)[310]
            ...
    protected 'minimoCaracteres' => int 3
    protected 'maximoCaracteres' => int 70
    protected 'attribute' => string 'Produto 1' (length=4)

array (size=3)
'id' => 
  object(Application\Model\Attribute\Id)[307]
    protected 'name' => string 'id' (length=2)
    protected 'attribute' => string '4' (length=1)
    protected 'validators' => 
      array (size=0)
        empty
'dataHoraCadastro' => 
  object(Application\Model\Attribute\DataHoraCadastro)[308]
    protected 'name' => string 'dataHoraCadastro' (length=16)
    protected 'attribute' => string '2015-03-07 14:03:37' (length=19)
    protected 'validators' => 
      array (size=0)
        empty
'nome' => 
  object(Application\Model\Attribute\Nome)[309]
    protected 'name' => string 'nome' (length=4)
    protected 'validators' => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => 
          object(Application\Validator\StringLengthValidator)[310]
            ...
    protected 'minimoCaracteres' => int 3
    protected 'maximoCaracteres' => int 70
    protected 'attribute' => string 'Produto 2' (length=9)
```

`$users`, `$produtos` and `$ros` are arrays of entities. The code of **findEntity** and **findAllEntities** methods are:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function findEntity($id) {
    $result = $this->executeFindSql($id);

    if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult()) {
        return $this->hydrator->hydrate($result->current(), $this->entity);
    }
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function findAllEntities() {
    $result = $this->executeFindSql();

    if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult()) {
        $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet($this->hydrator, $this->entity);

        return $resultSet->initialize($result);
    }

    return array();
}
```

The problem is that $produtos and $users arrays have the entire array overwritten on call of findEntity method. Seems that on each iteration, the full array is replaced with the last entity. Then, in the second iteration, the index 0 of $produtos array don't have the same value that in the first iteration...

By the end of loop, each element on the array have the last entity...very strange. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem some months ago. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960001/3753202). The problem is that the attributes of my entities are objects, not scalar variables. Then, I needed implement the clone method:

```
public function __clone() {
    foreach ($this->attributes as &$attribute) {
        $attribute = clone $attribute;
    }
    ... clone of another variables that are objects
}
```

In the end, this is a question more about clone than about zf2 hydrators and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem. I am assuming you based this code on the tutorial like I did. Well the problem is in the tutorial.

replace

`$resultSet = new HydratingResultSet($this->hydrator, $this->entity);`

with

`$resultSet = new HydratingResultSet($this->hydrator, clone $this->entity);`

That did it for me.

Good Luck.

Comment: Did you put `clone $this->entity` for this line too  `return $this->hydrator->hydrate($result->current(), $this->entity);` ?

Comment: you need to put `clone` for the `$this->entity`

Comment: First, I put `clone $this->entity` on the line `$resultSet = new HydratingResultSet($this->hydrator, $this->entity)`. Then, I put on the line `return $this->hydrator->hydrate($result->current(), $this->entity);` too. But, yet without success.